# In array key issue CakePHP Find conditions using list method

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I need result for Cakephp find list conditions using default array key not primary id wise

I have execute below code

```
$products = $this->Product->find('list', array(
                                            'contain' => array(),
                                            'fields' => array('Product.id'),                                              
                                        ));
```

Based on above code i got result mention below.

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
```

on below (array key must be in index wise)

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

Comment: use `array_values($products)`.

Comment: array_values to get the values only from array to return with numeric key

Comment: Always specify your exact CakePHP version.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Set:classicExtract function of Cakephp

```
$products = $this->Product->find('all', array(
                                            'contain' => array(),
                                            'fields' => array('Product.id'),                                              
                                        ));

$products = Set::classicExtract($products, '{n}.Product');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to achieve what you require here. Like so,

```
$products = array_values($products);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it through `array_values()` which will re-index your array:

```
$products = array_values( $products );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Answer (score 0):

[array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically. start from **0 to N**

```
$products = array_values($products);
```